# filter criteria with the OAI-PMH request to get the filtered result.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, oai

In my MVC app(c#) I have a url which returns an xml whose complete size is 1000+ records.
But it returns only 1000 records by default and further records can be retrieved using the resumptionToken taken from previous response. 
My question is can i pass some filter criteria with this url to get the filtered data from 1000+ records at a time.(other than from ,set,until)Eg: to filter records whose type is "books". Please help.

Answer (score 0):

OAI-PMH does not support any other filter than `from`, `until` and `set`, but some OAI-PMH interfaces implement custom filters via a special syntax in the `set` field. Check your provider's documentation to know if it is the case. Otherwise all you can do is to download all records and filter them by yourself.